# Print object key/values in a csv format

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print a object in comma seperated strings format. but I'm unable to understand how to concat keys for objects. Here is an example.

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Family",
  "count": 6,
  "Children": {
    "name": "Jim",
    "age": "24",
    "address": {
      "street": "5th ave",
      "state": "NY",
      "country":"US"
    }
  },
  "parents": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "45",
    "address": {
      "street": "New brew st",
      "state": "CA",
      "country":null
    }
  }
};

let data = '';
let tempKey = '';

function printValues(obj) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
       printValues(obj[key]);
    } else {
      data += key + ' - ' + obj[key] + ',';
    }
    tempKey = '';
  }
  return data;
} 
console.log(printValues(obj));
```

Here my target is to get the output below format.

> "name - Family,count - 6,Children_name - Jim,Children_age -
> 24,Children_address_street - 5th ave,Children_address_state -
> NY,Children_address_country - US,parents_name - John,parents_age -
> 45,parents_address_street - New brew st,parents_address_state -
> CA,parents_address_country - null"

my current output is

> "name - Family,count - 6,name - Jim,age - 24,street - 5th ave,state -
> NY,country - US,name - John,age - 45,street - New brew st,state - CA,"

I'm a bit confused about how to do this.

Comment: I've removed references to "nested JSON" since there's no JSON in the question

Comment: you correctly listed those properties naming them as a chain of the property names holding the nested objects. I don't understand the question and what's actually asking for

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I updated my question with my current output. In the expected output, I want the json keys concatenated as per the hierarichy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should keep track of the parent property name on your recursive calls so that you'll append that prefix if any was passed.

Here I added that argument to your function and I use it to compose the key string used when you "serialize" your object.

I used template literals to make string composition:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Family",
  "count": 6,
  "Children": {
    "name": "Jim",
    "age": "24",
    "address": {
      "street": "5th ave",
      "state": "NY",
      "country":"US"
    }
  },
  "parents": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "45",
    "address": {
      "street": "New brew st",
      "state": "CA",
      "country":null
    }
  }
};

let data = '';
let tempKey = '';

function printValues(obj, parent = '') {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] != null && typeof obj[key] === "object") {
       printValues(obj[key], `${parent}${key}_`);
    } else {
      data += `${parent}${key}` + ' - ' + obj[key] + ',';
    }
    tempKey = '';
  }
  return data;
} 
console.log(printValues(obj));
```

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation. I'll keep this in mind the next time I do it. :-)

Comment: Just a QQ @Diego, how can I get to display `"country":null `even?

Comment: I added a better condition when checking if the prop is an object. The condition didn't consider that null == 'object' is true. By the way, in fairness, the other solution is more complete and more clear. I just happened to arrive first here. I gave it an upvote

Answer (score 2):

#### Recursive solution (based on your solution)

You could use an additional `path` parameter. The rest of your code is already working fine. Whenever you encounter an object add the new key to the path array.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "Family",
  count: 6,
  Children: {
    name: "Jim",
    age: "24",
    address: {
      street: "5th ave",
      state: "NY",
      country: "US",
    },
  },
  parents: {
    name: "John",
    age: "45",
    address: {
      street: "New brew st",
      state: "CA",
      country: null,
    },
  },
};

let data = '';
let tempKey = '';

function printValues(obj, path = []) {
  for (var key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
       printValues(obj[key], path=[...path, key]);
    } else {
      
      data += path.join("_") + (path.length !== 0 ? "_": "") + key + ' - ' + obj[key] + ',';
    }
    tempKey = '';
  }
  return data;
} 
console.log(printValues(obj));
```

Another hint:

In order to check if something is an Object `typeof x === "object"` is not enough, as that would also be true for an `Array` or `null`. Use the following instead to make sure you are actually dealing with an object.

```js
/**
 * Checks whether an item is a JavaScript object
 * @param {any} item item to be checked
 * @returns true, if it is an object, false otherwise
 */
function isObject(item) {
  return typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null;
}
```

#### Iterative solution

I've gone ahead and also implemented a iterative solution for your problem. The result will be the same but instead of using recursion for backtracking one has to do the backtracking oneself. I do that here using a Stack and a Queue of props to investigate.

```js
let obj = {
  name: "Family",
  count: 6,
  Children: {
    name: "Jim",
    age: "24",
    address: {
      street: "5th ave",
      state: "NY",
      country: "US",
    },
  },
  parents: {
    name: "John",
    age: "45",
    address: {
      street: "New brew st",
      state: "CA",
      country: null,
    },
  },
};

/**
 * Checks whether an item is a JavaScript object
 * @param {any} item item to be checked
 * @returns true, if it is an object, false otherwise
 */
function isObject(item) {
  return typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null;
}

function printValuesIter(obj) {
  let str = "";
  if (!isObject(obj)) return str;
  // have a stack which determine which is the next object to investigate
  // for each stack object keep:
  // - a reference to the object
  // - a list ob properties that have yet to be investigated
  // - a path
  const stack = [{ cur: obj, propQueue: Object.keys(obj), path: [] }];
  // as long as we have not investigated every single object 
  while (stack.length !== 0) {
    // get next object from the stack
    const { cur, propQueue, path } = stack.pop();
    // as long as this object still has props we have not investigated
    while (propQueue.length !== 0) {
      // get the next prop from the queue
      const curProp = propQueue.shift();
      // check whether this prop is an object
      if (isObject(cur[curProp])) {
        // we have a new object
        if (propQueue.length !== 0){
          // the object we're currently investigating still has props that we have not yet looked at
          // => push it onto the stack again 
          stack.push({ cur: cur, propQueue: propQueue, path: path });
        }
        // add new object to stack as this is the next object we need to investigate
        stack.push({ cur: cur[curProp], propQueue: Object.keys(cur[curProp]), path: [...path, curProp]});
        // to get the new object from the stack we need to break here 
        break;
      // no object we can output this prop  
      } else str += `${path.length ? `${path.join("_")}_`: ""}${curProp} - ${cur[curProp]}, `;
    }
  }
  return str;
}

console.log(printValuesIter(obj));
```